# OpenCart not loading properly

Tags: opencart2.x

Hi guys 
Im currently installing opencart 

 image A.) in the server which i get the  error (Linux)

 image B.) at my local Computer completely okay (Windows)

[image: A -> B]
I try to to disable page protector by clicking the shield icon at the side of UrL or
disable this **security.mixed_content.block_active_content** at about:config in my firefox

any idea whats happen to image A?

 as i trying things here....
if i go to install/ folder its said 
[image]

is it the 8081 making things wrong?

thanks even for those who just read this :) 

and those who have suggestion to my problem,

 big "THANKS" hehehe

Comment: Is the remote server running *nginx*? The fact remote server is running on different port from the default HTTP one (8081 instead of 80 or 8080) may cause incorrect resources serving. Try to add this port into your `config.php` under the *`HTTP_`* defines.

Answer (score 0):

change directory permission 764 solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to configurate opencart to use https , after you install ,in your admin panel ->system->setting->server  put yes in SSL.

regards